# What design patterns for marshalling JSON APIs to/from SQL

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-web-api, api-design, data-modeling

I'm working on a first JSON-RPC/JSON-REST API. One of the conveniences of JSON is that it can easily represent structured data (a user may have multiple email addresses, multiple addresses), etc...

For example, the Facebook Graph API nicely represents the kind of thing that's handy to return as JSON objects:
https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/851559_339008529558010_1864655268_n.png

However, in implementing an API such as this with a relational database, we end up shattering structured objects into very many tables (at least one for each list in the JSON object), and un-shattering them when responding to requests. So:

- requires a lot of modelling (separate models for JSON object and SQL tables).
- inconsistencies creep in between the models: e.g. user_id (in SQL) vs. userID (in JSON)
- marshaling stuff between one model and the other is very time consuming (tedious, error-prone and pointless boilerplate).

What design-patterns exist to help in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are looking for design patterns. I would look for tools that handle this better.

I assume that you want to be able to query these objects, and not just store them in TEXT fields. Many databases support XML fairly well, so I would convert the JSON to XML (with a library) and then store that in the database.

You may also want to consider a JSON document based database. That will definitely get you where you want to go.

If you don't need to be able to query these, or only need to query a very small subset of fields, just store the objects as text, and extract those query-able fields into actual columns. This way you don't need to touch the majority of the data, but you can still query the few fields you care about. (Plus you can index them for speedier lookup.)

Answer (score 1):

I have always chosen to implement this functionality in a facade pattern. Since the point of the facade is to simplify (abstract) an underlying complexity as a boundary between two or more systems, it seemed like the perfect place to handle this.

I realize however that this does not quite answer the question. I am talking about the container for the marshalling while the question is about how to better manage the contents (the code that does the job).

My approach here is somewhat old fashioned, but since this an old question maybe that’s okay. I employ (as much as possible) stored procedures in the dB. This promotes better encapsulation than one typically finds with a code layer outside of the dB that has to “know about” dB structure. What inevitably happens in the latter case is that more than one system will be written to do this (one large company I worked at had at least 6 competing ESBs) and there will be conflicts. Also, usually the stored procedure scripting will benefit from some sort of IDE that will helps maintain contextual awareness of the dB structure.

So this approach - even though it is not a pattern per se - makes managing the ORM a lot easier.